# Import-GPO by using folders named after its DisplayName - Powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I am using a powershell script to import GPOs which I have saved as GUIDs (the default).

I wish to import the GPOs on a different system, the GPOs are saved to a CD at this point.  So a simple way to import a single GPO would be:

```
$domain=[System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.Domain]::GetCurrentDomain().Name

$import_array = get-childitem ($current_drive + $gpo_backup_location) | Select name
foreach ($GPO in $import_array) {
Import-GPO |
-backupgponame $GPO.name -path ($Current_Drive + $gpo_backup_location) |
-domain $domain | 
-Targetname $GPO.name |
-migrationtable ($Current_drive + $mig_table_path) |
-Createifneeded;
}
}
```

the $import_array command gives me my folder names

```
Name
----------
GPO-1
GPO-2
GPO-3
GPO-4
and so on...
```

I want to iterate over these and import each one.  The GPOs are saved using another block of code to backup the GPOs as their displayname.  (GPO-1, GPO-2, etc.,)

I cannot for the life of me figure out how to force it to look at the folder name and to import these

### EDIT

---

The Backup was created with the following code:

```
Function GPO_Backup_DisplayName ($MenuChoice) {
    write 'Backing Up GPOs by Display Name'
    Foreach ($GPO in $GPO_Temp_Backup) {
        $GPOBackup = Backup-GPO `
            -name $GPO.DisplayName `
            -path ($Current_drive + $GPO_Backup_Location) `
            -Domain $domain;
        Get-GPOReport $GPO.DisplayName `
            -reporttype HTML `
            -Domain $domain `
            -path ($Current_drive + $GPO_Backup_HTML_Report + $GPO.DisplayName + ".html");
        Rename-item 
            -path ($Current_drive + $GPO_Backup_Location + "{" + $GPOBackup.Id + "}") `
            -newname $GPO.DisplayName
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you export each GPO to its own folder and name that folder after the GPO, you can iterate over these folders in a `foreach` loop to import the GPOs and set the target name to the folder name. Something like this should work:

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\backup" | % {
  $name = $_.name
  $id = (get-childitem $_) -replace '[{}]', ''
  Import-GPO -BackupId $id -TargetName $name -path $_.Path -CreateIfNeeded
}
```

Prerequisite is that you created the backups with something like this:

```
Get-GPO -All | % {
  $name = $_.DisplayName
  $dir = New-Item "C:\backup\$name" -Type Directory
  Backup-GPO -Guid $_.Id -Path $dir
}
```

Also, the backup directory should contain only the folders with the single GPO backups, otherwise you'll have to add a filter between `Get-ChildItem` and `ForEach-Object`.

Comment: Can you provide a more detailed example?  I have it setup to save the GPOs as its DisplayName.  This is working correctly, but when I try to import these, it gives me the error `the gpo cannot be imported because a gpo backup that is named "Our Name" was not found at domain.com`  I will update my question to support my new code

Comment: Is this just creating empty folders, I can't seem to get it to work properly.  Would it just be better to output the names to a text file?  I would rather not do this I was hoping there might be a way to get this to work without the use of text files but I haven't been able to get it.

Comment: That's because I forgot to assign the result of `New-Item` to the variable `$dir`. Sorry about that, it's fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

List Group Policy Object using PowerShell